# Spring Metrics Always on Random Port

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

I'm using micrometer along with spring actuator to expose Prometheus metrics. I have the following configs:

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

However, the management server always starts on a random port. It seems that the `management.server.port` property doesn't work at all. `localhost:28081/prometheus` doesn't work, but the one with the random port works.

This is the management server starts log:

```
[org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer(108)] - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 28014 (http)
[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol(173)] - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-28014"]
[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol(173)] - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-28014"]
[org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer(220)] - Tomcat started on port(s): 28014 (http) with context path ''
```

The port number `28014` changes every time the app starts.